# Ubuntu install hangs

Tags: 11.10, installation

When I try to install/run ubuntu from a liveCD, it just hangs on this screen...

[image: screenshot1]

Any ideas?

I've unplugged all my usb devices other than my death adder mouse and g15 keyboard, tried 32bit and 64bit 11.10 but both do the same thing.

Ran the memory test on the ubuntu install CD and it was fine.

Thanks,

pc specs..
`Asus P5Q motherboard Q6700 cpu 4gig dominator 1066mhz corsair 1tb HDD Asus 560ti graphics card`

edit : after unplugging all my usb devices (putting a new keyboard in) and disabling firewire on my motherboard in the bios, I get the image below...

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: What video chip do you use?
Did you MD5 test the ISO you downloaded?
Did you burn the CD as slowly as possible?

Comment: I use an asus 560ti.  I didn't md5 the download, but i tried two different ISO's.  I will try burning a third CD.

Comment: I made it on 5th CD. =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was my 560ti that it didn't like.  Booted with [`nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Once you burn the .iso to the CD/DVD, be sure to check '**Verify disc after burning**' / '**Verify disc**' check box on your burn application. This is rareley useful, but could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I did do this :<

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing but it looks like a bad RAM chip on the video card.  If I were you I would figure out how to scan the ram on the video card  OR  figure out how to install in VGA mode (maybe with a boot arg to the installer?).